# How can I set a string variable which is different for each environment?

Tags: grails

How can I set up a string variable which has different values for `dev` and `prod` environments and use it in my code depending on the environment I am running in.

Right now I'm doing it by just commenting code and when I forget to uncomment it before deploying to production, it is a PITA. I build the WAR by `grails prod war target/my.war`

```
//        String url_path = "http://servicerunningonprod"
        String url_path = "http://servicerunninglocal"
```

Comment: Look into [`Config.groovy`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments) is how Grails handles it. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, here is what we have found most useful.

1. Store all your properties e.g. url_path in a properties file.
2. Create multiple set of properties each one for dev, uat and prod.
3. This property file is not pacakged with any release.
4. DEV, UAT & PROD boxes store this file at same path in their environment.
5. When updated code is release on DEV, UAT or PROD they pick up there specific properties file.

Hope this help !!

Cheers !!